# Shorthand for checking for equality to multiple possibilities

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ comparing bunch of values with a given one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639496/c-comparing-bunch-of-values-with-a-given-one)

I'm needing to check for equality in a for loop in C++, however the loop needs to work for x equaling multiple possibilities.

For example, right now I have something similar to:

```
if(x==a || x==b || x==c || x==d || x==e || x==f || x==g || x==h)
{
    //loop body
}
```

But with the number I have, it looks messy and I was wondering if there was a shorthand way of saying "if (x == (any of these))" or if writing them all out was the only option.

Thanks!

Comment: You can put them in a container and use `find`.

Comment: If `x` is an integer or enumeration type, you can use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Also, if such comparison has to be done repeatedly against the same numbers you may put them in an array, *sort it* and do a binary search (it should be faster than a hashtable for a limited number of elements).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672593/easy-way-to-check-if-item-is-in-list answer your question?

Comment: I would prefer your original approach. It is more optimal than using containers, and if any equality test returns true the other statements will not be executed. It might not be your finest work, but it works and it is reasonably optimal.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your question, now as I found a solution (and an elegant one I dare say), I'll use it myself.

Unlike solutions with std::find : Will a ) be unrolled to N comparisons in compile time  b) work with any types which X can be compared to

```
struct TagAnyOf {};

template <typename... Args>
std::tuple <TagAnyOf, Args...> AnyOf (Args&&... args)
{
   return std::tuple <TagAnyOf, Args...> (TagAnyOf(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class X, class Tuple, size_t Index, size_t ReverseIndex>
struct CompareToTuple
{
    static bool compare (const X& x, const Tuple& tuple)
    {
        return x == std::get<Index> (tuple) || CompareToTuple<X, Tuple, Index+1, ReverseIndex-1>::compare (x, tuple);
    }
};

template <class X, class Tuple, size_t Index>
struct CompareToTuple <X, Tuple, Index, 0>
{
    static bool compare (const X& x, const Tuple& tuple)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename X, typename... Args>
bool operator == (const X& x, const std::tuple<TagAnyOf, Args...>& any)
{
    typedef std::tuple <TagAnyOf, Args...> any_of_type;
    return CompareToTuple <X, any_of_type, 1, std::tuple_size<any_of_type>::value-1>::compare (x, any);
}
```

Usage

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    if (x == AnyOf (1, 2, 3, 4))
    {
        std::cout << "Yes!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (x == AnyOf (4, 3, 2, 1))
    {
        std::cout << "Yes!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (x == AnyOf (2, 3, 4, 5))
    {
        std::cout << "Yes!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, but what is the role of the struct `TagAnyOf`, which you use as the first tuple element?

Comment: Oh, one more comment: Not a problem, but it should be mentioned that the recursive tuple-approach evaluates the comparison from right to left. That is, in `x == AnyOf(2,3,4,5)`, `x` will first be compared to `5`, then, failing that, to `4`, then, failing that, to `3` and so on. In a traditional `(x == 2) || (x == 3) ||...` statement, many people tend to put the _most likely_ value of `x` first, because then the remaining conditions need not be evaluated. If your `AnyOf`  is used, you should put the most likely value in the rightmost position.

Comment: @jogojapan, it's to distinguish between tuples produced by AnyOf and all others - to avoid surprises.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: @jogojapan, good point, thanks. I changed it a bit, now comparison goes left -> right

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a function that takes an initializer_list (this is a c++11 feature).
the first parameter would be the left hand value(x in your case), and the rest of the parameters will be right hand values.

---

Here is an example that accomplishes the task using templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T> 
bool Test(T const& test, std::initializer_list<T> const& values){
    return std::find(std::begin(values), std::end(values), test) != std::end(values);
}

int main(){

    char var1 = 'a';
    char var2 = 'a';
    char var3 = 'b';
    char var4 = 'c';
    char var5 = 'd';

    if (Test<char>(var1,{var2,var3,var4,'o',var5})){
        std::cout << "true. at least one is equivelent" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "false. none are equivelent" << std::endl;
    }

    if (Test<char>(var1,{var3,var4,var5})){
        std::cout << "true. at least one is equivelent" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "false. none are equivelent" << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you are doing this with classes, make sure you overload the '!=' operator.

**edit:** mistake fixed. pointed out by GManNickG

Comment: Your logic is backwards. This is equivalent to requiring it equals *all* of the test cases (because if its not equal to one you say false). Test for equality and return true if so. OP is asking about `||` not `&&`.

Comment: Much better. :) Note the body of `Test` can be replaced with `return std::find(std::begin(values), std::end(values), test) != std::end(values)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a shorthand way of saying "if (x == (any
>   of these))"

Yes, the standard gives you `std::find` and `std::find_if` to answer exactly this question:

```
int a=3,b=5,c=6,d=7;
std::array<int,4> vals{{a,b,c,d}}; // or std::vector
int x=5;
bool foundit= (end(vals) != std::find_if(begin(vals), end(vals),x );
```

You will need

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
```

You can also use `std::initializer_list<int> booleans{a,b,c,d};` instead of `vector` or `array`

If your conditions where more complicated, you could use find_if:

```
 bool foundit= (end(vals) != 
               std::find_if(begin(vals), end(vals),
                            [&x](const int &v){return v*(v+x)<x;}));
```

Comment: If your predicate is just going to be `x == y`, just use `std::find`.